# Javascript regex error " /?/: nothing to repeat " It worked fine earlier

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to clear a string of any invalid characters to be set as a directory. 
Tried a number of methods and this one eventually worked[custom encoding] but now it doesn't, it says "nothing to repeat" in the console. What does that mean? using Chrome.

Here's the code(using random string):

```
var someTitle = "wa?";
var cleanTitle = cleanTitle(someTitle);

function cleanTitle(title){

    var obstructions = ['\\','/',':','*','?','"','<','>','|'];
    var solutions = [92,47,58,42,63,34,60,62,124];
    var encodedTitle = title;

    for (var obstruction = 0; obstruction < obstructions.length; obstruction++){
            var char = obstructions[obstruction];

            if (encodedTitle.includes(char)){
                var enCode = "__i!__"+solutions[obstruction]+"__!i__";
                var rEx = new RegExp(char,"g");
                encodedTitle = encodedTitle.replace(rEx,enCode);
            }
    }

    console.log("CLEAN: "+title);
    console.log("ENCODED: "+encodedTitle);


    return encodedTitle;
}
```

Heres the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /?/: Nothing to
>   repeat

It points to this line -> `var rEx = new RegExp(char,"g");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape some characters when using them as literals in a regular expression. Among those are most of the characters you have in your array.

Given your function replaces the obstruction characters with their ASCII code (and some wrapping `__i!__`), I would suggest to make your function a bit more concise, by performing the replacement with one regular expression, and a callback passed to `.replace()`:

```js
function cleanTitle(title){
    return title.replace(/[\\/:*?"<>|]/g, function (ch) {
        return "__i!__"+ch.charCodeAt(0)+"__!i__";
    });
}  

var someTitle = "wh*r* is |his?";
var result = cleanTitle(someTitle);

console.log(result);
```

...and if you are in an ES6 compatible environment:

```js
var cleanTitle = t=>t.replace(/[\\/:*?"<>|]/g, c=>"__i!__"+c.charCodeAt(0)+"__!i__"); 

var someTitle = "wh*r* is |his?";
var result = cleanTitle(someTitle);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `?` is a regex modifier. When you want to look for it (and build a regex with it), you need to escape it.
That beeing said, a harmless unuseful escaping doesn't hurt (or makes your other search params useable, as there are many modifiers or reserved chars in it) your other search params. So go with

```
var char = '\\' + obstructions[obstruction];
```

to replace them all with a (for the regex) string representation

Comment: That didn't help, it worked better putting it in this line: var rEx = new RegExp('\\' + char,"g");

Comment: Ah, I didn't care for your `if` statement @LlamaObama

Answer (score 0):

`/?/` is not a valid regex. For it to be a regex, you need `/\?/`.

Regex here would be awkward, as most of the characters need escaping. Instead, consider using a literal string replacement until it is no longer found:

```
while( encodedTitle.indexOf(char) > -1) {
    encodedTitle = encodedTitle.replace(char,enCode);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! its working!!